# Transferring Images through rosbridge

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, rosbridge-server, rosbridge

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using the rosbridge websocket server to establish communication between ROS and an environment simulation tool. I can easily exchange scalar values like the object list and the control signals.
Now I want to transfer the images from the camera of the environment simulation tool to ROS, also through the rosbridge.

Is there a small example ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/313300/transferring-images-through-rosbridge/) by [aks](https://answers.ros.org/users/34222/aks/) on ROS Answers with karma: 667 on 2019-01-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`roslibpy` works exactly the same as `roslibjs`, so you could -most likely- check [this example](http://wiki.ros.org/roslibjs/Tutorials/Publishing%20video%20and%20IMU%20data%20with%20roslibjs) using `roslibjs` for video publishing (using message type `sensor_msgs/CompressedImage`) and adapt it to `roslibpy`, all the subscribing part should be almost identical, then the decoding will be python-specific, but it should not be any problem.

---

Originally posted by [gonzalocasas](https://answers.ros.org/users/34021/gonzalocasas/) with karma: 180 on 2019-04-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [aks](https://answers.ros.org/users/34222/aks/) on 2019-09-18**:
@gonzalocasas thank you for this example. One question here... is it necessary to use the (`sensor_msgs/CompressedImage`) as the message type ? Cant i use the normal (`sensor_msgs/Image`)

**Comment by [gonzalocasas](https://answers.ros.org/users/34021/gonzalocasas/) on 2019-09-18**:
you can also use image, of course, but you'd need to adapt it to do the corresponding decoding.